# Computing the number of permutations of n consecutive numbers

Tags: c++, beginner, combinatorics

I'm just starting to learn C++ and have been experimenting with various functions. Here is one that computes the number of permutations of *n* consecutive numbers as well as all possible permutations provided *n*. I'd love to receive any form of tips and criticisms on improving this function.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

string rotateRt(string input);
vector<string> permute(int num);

int main(){
    cout << "n: ";
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<string> permutations(permute(n));
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("rosalind_perm.txt");
    myfile << permutations.size() << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < permutations.size(); i++){
        myfile << permutations.at(i) << endl;
    }   
    myfile.close();
}

/* Rotate input string right by 1 character */
string rotateRt(string input){
    int len = input.length();
    string a, b;
    if(len == 0){
        return "";
    }
    else if(len == 1){
        return input;
    }
    else{
        a = input.substr(0, len - 2);
        b = input.substr(len - 1) + " ";
        return b + a;
    }   
}

/* To compute permutations we compute the permutations of num - 1,
append num to the front of each permutation, and find every cyclic
rotation. */
vector<string> permute(int num){
    vector<string> permutations;
    ostringstream convert;
    if(num == 1){
        permutations.push_back("1");
    }
    else{
        vector<string> prevPermutations(permute(num - 1));
        int size = prevPermutations.size();
        string prefix, suffix, word;
        convert << num;
        prefix = convert.str();
        convert.str("");
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            suffix = prevPermutations.at(i);
            word = prefix +  " " + suffix;
            int length = word.length();
            for(int j = 0; j < length / 2 + 1; j++){
                permutations.push_back(word);
                word = rotateRt(word);
            }
        }
    }
    return permutations;
}
```

Comment: You know there's an `std::permutations()` function in the standard library?

Comment: Try the [next_permutation] method (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/)

Comment: @h2co3 is that proposed for c++14? I don't know any library vendor that has that algorithm :/

Comment: I have yet to get into iterators and stl yet. Until next time I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to `Jamal`'s good points:

**1:** Consider sorting your `#include`s alphabetically. It's not a big issue, but I think it looks more tidy, and it's easier to see if something is already included or not.

**2:** Consider `typedef vector<string> StringCollection` (or some other meaningful name). This makes it easier to change the underlying data structure later, and makes the code look cleaner.

**3:** If you are using C++11, I'd write the `for` loop like this:

```
for (auto const& number : permutations) {
    myfile << number << endl;
}
```

Since you are learning, I see no reason not to get into C++11 right away.

**4:** Tutorials and the like often use `mySomething` as identifiers. `my` is a bad identifier prefix. Instead, write what role it has or what it represents. `outputFile` is much better than `myFile`.

**5:** Initialize variables right away. The `std::ofstream` constructor takes a filename, so there is no need to first initialize and then call `open()`.

**6:** Instantiate variables as late as possible. In your `rotateRt()` (which should be called `rotateRight()`, by the way), you don't have to create your `string`s unless the last `else` triggers. Change it to this:

```
else {
    string a = input.substr(0, len - 2);
    string b = input.substr(len - 1) + " ";
    return b + a;
}
```

The same applies to for example `ostringstream convert`.

When you instantiate a variable as late as possible, you avoid constructing it unless you really have to. "As late as possible" implies *as close as possible to the relevant context*, which makes the code easier to read.

**7:** Consider rewriting `permute()` to reduce nesting.

**8:** Your code would normally be better suited as a class. You don't have to think too much about this yet, since you just started with C++. It's a good exercise to refactor this to use classes later.

**9:** In the case of `int len = input.length();`, you should use `std::size_t` instead of `int`.

**10:** Prefer C++-style comments: `//` (*Effective C++* explains why, so I won't repeat it here.)

**11:** Use more whitespace. Especially more vertical whitespace. Insert an empty line in logical places to make your code much more readable.

**12:** You don't modify or copy the `string` you pass to `rotateRt`, so it should be reference-to-const instead: `rotateRt(string const& input)`. (If you prefer, you can write `const string&`, it's the same thing.)

**13:** Consider rewriting `permute()` so that it's not recursive. Recursive functions that create a couple of objects can quickly chew up a lot of memory, and are often not very efficient. In short, your `permute()` function can be improved a great deal.

**14:** Consider refactoring the file name out into a constant:

```
const string filename = "rosalind_perm.txt";
```

This way it's easier to find if you have to change it, and by using the constant you are guaranteed you will only have to change it in one location.

Comment: +1, but to be really pedantic, `int len` should be `std::string::size_type len` rather than `std::size_t`. I can't imagine any possible situation in which it would matter, but... Yeah... :)

Comment: I agree with all items except for the non-recursive rewrite of `permute`: unless there are pressing performance concerns, do *not* do this. Permutation is a naturally recursive operation, a recursive formulation of the problem is much clearer than an iterative one. For this reason it’s also much simpler.

Comment: The constructor for ostream takes in const char* for the filename. Would it be better to declare the const char* and then use it in the function call instead?

Comment: It has a constructor that takes a `std::string const&` as well. Do like this: `std::string filename = "bacon.txt";` and then `std::ofstream outputFile(filename)`.

Answer (score 4):

- Do not use `using namespace std`.  Learn more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).
- It looks nicer to put the `int n` above the user input code.  You could also give it a nicer name like `numberInput`.
- In all of your function bodies, separate different code line blocks with a newline.  In `main()`, for instance: separate the input variable, user input, file-checking, and `vector` insertions.  That way it's easier to see what each function is doing, thus increasing readability.
- If you're using C++11, consider this [range-based `for`-loop](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-ranged-for-loop.html) for your loop in `main()` and apply the same to your outer loop in `permute()`:

  ```
  for (auto const &iter : permutations)
  {
      myfile << iter << std::endl;
  }
  ```
- If you're not modifying the `input` parameter in `rotateRt()`, make it a `const&` instead:

  ```
  std::string rotateRt(std::string const& input) {}
  ```
- If you're checking to see if an `std::string` is empty, use `empty()` instead of `== 0`:

  ```
  if (input.empty())
      // do something
  ```
- No need to assign `input.length()` to a variable if you're not doing anything special with it.  Just use the accessor itself.
- What is `std::string a, b`?  Again, give your variables some nice names.  Single-character variables are usually preferred for simple loop-counters.  These variables could also be declared on separate lines for clarity.

Comment: I have trouble making choices between using .empty() and len == 0 as calling .empty() is another function call and since len is checked later anyway, I can avoid the extra overhead of calling empty(). Is this considered often or should I prioritize on understandable code?

Comment: @whytheman, calling `empty()` shouldn't be too costly as it is an inline function within the `class`.  That in mind, it is better to use that than `== 0` in terms of readability.  It also boosts maintainability a bit as you don't have to worry about `len == 0` accidentally changing; `empty()` will stay the same.